# Split XML file into multiple Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, xml-import

It seems Google Sheets has a limit of 8000 rows (approximately due to my little test).
I have an XML file URL containing several thousands of elements.
Because of that I'd like to split the XML file into multiple Google Sheets.

Is there some way I could select a range to import? E.g.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://example.com/file.xml", "//element", "formula-for-only-selecting 0-999")
```

Another way I'd like to split the XML file into multiple Sheets, would be to choose which types of elements to import based on additional data, such as "Name" contains "Jack". E.g.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://example.com/file.xml", "//element", "formula-for-only-selecting-elements-including-name-equals-jack")
```

This is how the XML file looks like:

```
<elements>
<element>
<link>
<![CDATA[ https://example.com/jones ]]>
</link>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Jones ]]>
</name>
</element>
<element>
<link>
<![CDATA[ https://example.com/jack ]]>
</link>
<name>
<![CDATA[ Jack ]]>
</name>
</element>
</elements>
```

Comment: pretty sure the limit is way more than 1000 rows

Comment: It returns #N/A and Error - Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size.
I'm trying to find a workaround, and the best way I could come up with was to split the xml file into multiple sheets.

Comment: In your situation, how about using Google Apps Script?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.